# checkAndUpdateEglState: invalid current EGLContext

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to use [Kickflip](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk/) as a streaming library in a project of mine.

Everything seems to be working fine, I receive the broadcast in my server perfectly. Except when I press the power button on Android and the screen goes blank, when returning back to the app I will get this error:

```
12-08 14:04:05.225 8514-9009/com.kelmer.myapp E/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-1-8514-0] checkAndUpdateEglState: invalid current EGLContext
12-08 14:04:05.229 8514-9009/com.kelmer.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 549
                                                                           Process: com.kelmer.myapp, PID: 8514
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to update texture contents (see logcat for details)
                                                                               at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:240)
                                                                               at io.kickflip.sdk.av.CameraSurfaceRenderer.onDrawFrame(CameraSurfaceRenderer.java:120)
                                                                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1553)
                                                                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1253)
```

I have no idea what this could mean, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The EGL context may be automatically freed by the operating system when the process is slept or pushed to the background in order to stop all of the system resources (both the EGL context, and the memory for the resources) being used up by backgrounded processes. The application has to reconstruct the EGL context (and all of the graphics resources) when the process is foregrounded again.

See the documentation on `onPause()` here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html

You can disable this (on some devices, it's not guaranteed to work, e.g. if the device does not support multiple EGL contexts and the foreground process needs one) using `setPreserveEGLContextOnPause()`, but this is discouraged as it locks up resources which the foreground application therefore can't use.